# historical Ethereum trading volume data at a minute interval

Tags: ether, gas-price, price, api

I want to access historical Ethereum trading volume and price data at a minute interval for the last six months, I found daily intervals but could not find for minute interval, any suggestion to find such data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access historical minute-level Ethereum trading volume and price data from various cryptocurrency data providers such as CoinGecko, CoinMarketCap, and CryptoCompare.

These platforms offer APIs that allow you to retrieve historical data at minute intervals for the last six months.
By using their APIs, you can easily access the specific data you are looking for and analyze Ethereum's trading volume and price movements in detail.

Additionally, you can consider using specialized financial data providers or cryptocurrency exchanges that offer historical minute-level data for Ethereum trading.